# angular2 send parameter using Rounting to child component

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, router

I am trying to send a child component (resultadoBusqueda.component) a series of parameters at the time of do click the button for a component, if I do " this.router.navigate(["./resultadoBusqueda"], navigationExtras);" does not work, while if I do with routerlink "Child One" it does work and loads the component child, the problem is that with routerlink I can not try a series of parameters to send them later, i need do it when with router.navigate. Any idea?

Busqueda.component.html

```
<button (click)="EnviarQueryParams()">Enviar query params a resultadoBusquedaComponent.ts</button>
<!--<a [routerLink]="['./resultadoBusqueda']">Child One</a>-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Busqueda.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, NavigationExtras} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
selector: 'app-busqueda-component',
templateUrl: './busqueda.component.html',
})

export class BusquedaComponent {
public constructor(private router: Router) { }

EnviarQueryParams(){
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        queryParams: {
            "firstname": "Nic",
            "lastname": "Raboy"
        }
    };
    this.router.navigate(["./resultadoBusqueda"], navigationExtras);
}
}
```

resultadoBusqueda.component.ts (Child component, this component load in router-outlet of "Busqueda.Component"

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";   

@Component({
 selector: 'app-resultado-busqueda-component',
 templateUrl: './resultadoBusqueda.component.html',
 providers: [EmployeeService]
})

export class ResultadoBusquedaComponent  implements OnInit {  
public firstname: string;
public lastname: string;
constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService,private route: 
ActivatedRoute) {    }    

ngOnInit() {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.firstname = params["firstname"];
  this.lastname = params["lastname"];    
});
}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
// Some stuff ...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'busqueda', component: BusquedaComponent,
children: [{path: 'resultadoBusqueda',  component: 
ResultadoBusquedaComponent}]
},  
{ path: 'employees', component: EmployeeListComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

// Some stuff ...
imports: [
 BrowserModule, FormsModule,  Ng2CompleterModule, HttpModule,  
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)    
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query params with `RouterLink` as well. It's discussed [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description) in the Angular docs.

You can add your query params like this:

```
<a routerLink="resultadoBusqueda" [queryParams]="navigationExtras">Child One</a>
```

Comment: I can not do this because the variable "resultadoBusqueda" is populated when I click on the button. It is populated based on a number of criteria that I have to check when I click the button and not before.